# 2^n - 1 without overflowing a long

Tags: c, undefined, standards, integer-overflow, c89

This is for a C89 project, in which `LONG_IS_64BIT` is defined if (and only if) a `long` is 64-bit, that is, contains all the integers from -2^63-1 to 2^63-1. Otherwise (by the C standard) it contains all the integers from -2^31-1 to 2^31-1.

I have a number `n` which is guaranteed to be from 0 to 63 (inclusive) if `LONG_IS_64BIT` is defined or 0 to 31 (inclusive) otherwise. I would like to compute 2^n-1, which fits inside a long.

At the moment the code has `(1L<<n) - 1`, but in the highly-likely case that `long`s are exactly 32 or 64 bits, this is undefined behavior. (In this part of the program `n==63` is almost impossible, but on a 32-bit computer `n==31` could definitely happen.) What's the right way to do this?

I suppose I could just test for `n==31` and `n==63` but that feels hacky.

Comment: If you want it to be truly portable, do an ifdef check with hardcoded constants.

Comment: @2501 Yes, that's how I tell which case I'm in. There are `#ifdef LONG_IS_64BIT` tests all over the code. But what do I write instead of `(1L<<n)-1`? I could use `n==31 ? 0x7FFFFFFF : (1LL<<n)-1` (and similarly for the other case), but is that the best I can do?

Comment: "Otherwise (by the C standard) it contains all the integers from -2^31 to 2^31-1." -- No, the C standard doesn't guarantee that. It guarantees at least 32 bits, but if exactly 32 bits, the values may go from -(2^31-1) to 2^31-1 instead. Those implementations are extremely uncommon. Are you looking for something you can use 100% portably, or something that works for the implementations you'll deal with? If the latter, which ones are they?

Comment: Depends on what the meaning of *best* is in your circumstance.

Comment: `(long)((1UL << n) - 1)`

Comment: @melpomene That might work -- maybe post as an answer? (I'm looking up the standard on the other issue, thanks for the pointer.)

Comment: @melpomene That can still fail according to C. The precision of unsigned long could be the same as of signed long.

Comment: @2501 In what situation would it fail?

Comment: @melpomene I've described it in the comment.

Comment: @2501 I didn't know that, but I don't think it would lead to any problems here.

Comment: @melpomene In 64 bit mode, long has a precision of 63 bits. But nothing is said for unsigned long. Of course it should have a precision of 64 bits, but C allows it to have a precision of 63 bits. In which case the operation `1UL<<n` would wrap-around.

Comment: @2501 Good point!

Comment: BTW, if you support arbitrary `long` sizes (say, 36 bits) and only use up to 32 bits in that case, you could choose to define `LONG_IS_64BIT` only if `long` and `unsigned long` *both* have 64 bits. That would allow the `1UL` version to work. The 63-bit `unsigned long` implementation would just be treated as another not-64-bit implementation, which seems fair.

Comment: Not sure about this but.... Would it be possible to use right shift on the types MAX from <limits.h>. For instance like: `(LLONG_MAX >> (63-n))`

Comment: @4386427 That won't work, but that general idea will, and I was just typing up an answer including that as an option. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know the mathematical value of `(1L<<n)-1` fits in `long`, you can ensure you don't overflow by calculating the value minus one, and then adding one, rather than calculating the value plus one, and then subtracting one.

```
n == 0 ? 1 : ((1L<<n-1)-1<<1)+1
```

It's convoluted, requiring special casing to avoid left shift by a negative value if `n == 0`, but at least it gets you the value you need.

Alternatively, you can use a right shift:

```
#ifdef LONG_IS_64BIT
0x7FFFFFFFFFFFFFFF>>(63-n)
#else
0x7FFFFFFF>>(31-n)
#endif
```

You can't use `LONG_MAX` here if it could well be larger than you expect.

Realistically though, @melpomene's comment to use `unsigned long` should be good enough. The platforms where it has the same amount of value bits as `long` were already uncommon back when the standard was written. And if you already sort of assume `long` will have exactly 32 or exactly 64 bits, you probably shouldn't worry about the more esoteric implementations.

Comment: Not sure I understand how `LONG_MAX` can be `larger than you expect` when the type are known to be either 32 or 64 bits.

Comment: @4386427 `long` is not known to be either 32 or 64 bits, at least not based on the info in the question. Based on the info in the question, it's only known to be at least 32 bits based on the standard, or at least 64 bits if a specific macro gets defined. But I do acknowledge the OP may well already be assuming it is exactly 32 or exactly 64 bits.

Comment: @hvd I know `LONG_MAX` can't be trusted. :)